# Regex That Recognizes the Beginning and End of Python While Condition

Tags: python, regex

Note that this language is not python, but a rather a language that is very much like python in the configuration of the while/if statements. Assuming that there will always be this configuration of statements:

```
while something:
[tab] do those things
continue with other statements
```

The syntax is akin to python. I am able to match the beginning of the statement with `while\:[\n\t]` but am not able to escape to the other statements. The regex I used for matching the closing of the while is `[\n^\t]`, but does not work. An interesting thing to note is that if I changed the above code to look like this:

```
while something:
[tab] do those things
Q;
continue with other statements
```

Then the ending regex "Q;" will only execute those things in the while loop something-many times. How do I get the regex to match correctly for non-hardcoded values such a Q;?

Comment: If you want to parse code, you should probably use a parser, [not regular expressions](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: @Mariano which part of your solution covers the ending of the block?

Comment: The Q; was just an example of a variable statement. What I am trying to do is not hardcode a value, but rather have a general way to break out of this while-loop block, which is why I thought that look for the next line that did't start with a tabs, hence [^ \t ] but that is not working

Comment: @user3044396 In Python you don't need another statement to break out of while loops, as it ends as soon as there's a line with a lower indentation level (you don't need to look for a line with no tabs, just less spaces/tabs than the previous). That's what [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/eG9wM8/1), referenced in [my anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33588816/5290909) is doing