# Finding Last Occurrence of a Sequence Regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing

```
while something:
     do something;
     do somethingelse;
     do thelastthing;
continue with other statements..
```

I am attempting to create a regex that will only match the last statement in the while loop only. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: In what language? Most languages provide methods for getting the last occurrence or at the very least a list of all occurrences which would give you access to the last item.

Comment: what text are you trying to match?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Matching Everything Within a Python If Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587745/regex-matching-everything-within-a-python-if-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably give more information for a more clear answer.
Why don't you control the loop with a variable, let's say "c", using it as a "Go in/ Don't go in" variable ?
Example:

```
c = 0
while c == 0:
if thisistrue:
    c = 1
else:
    dosomething
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33588816/5290909), you can capture the indentation level of your while loop with

```
^([ \t]*)  while\b
```

and then match each line with the same indentation level `\1` *plus* at least one space.

```
\n\1  [ \t]+  (?P<last_statement>.*)
```

**Code**

```
import re

while_loop = re.compile(r'''
            #while statement (group 1 captures the indentation)
            ^([ \t]*)  while\b  .*  $

            #code
            (?:
                #comments with any indentation
                (?:
                    \s*?
                    \n  [ \t]*  [#].* 
                )*

                #Optional else lines
                (?:
                    \s*?
                    \n\1  else  [ \t]*  .*  $
                )?

                #following lines with more indentation
                \s*?
                \n\1  [ \t]+  (?P<last_statement>.*)
            )*

            \n?
''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)


test_str = r'''
            while something:
                do something;
                do somethingelse;
                do thelastthing;
            continue with other statements..
'''


# Loop matches
m = 0
for match in while_loop.finditer(test_str):
    m += 1
    print( 'Match #%s [%s:%s]\nLast statement [%s:%s]:\t"%s"' 
        %(m, match.start(), match.end(), match.start("last_statement"),
        match.end("last_statement"), match.group("last_statement")))

if m == 0:
    print("NO MATCH")
```

**Output**

```
Match #1 [1:91]
Last statement [74:90]: "do thelastthing;"
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/V0H19n)</kbd>